# merge two tables to update the existing table with new data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `old_data` and a table `new_data`. I want to write a select statement that give me

1. Rows in old_data stay there
2. New rows in new_data get added to old_data
3. unique key is `id` so rows with `id` in `new_data` should update existing ones in `old_data`

I need to write  a select statement(I believe it should have joins) that would give me old_data updated with new data and new data added to it.

Example:

Table a:

```
id         count

1             2
2            19
3             4
```

Table b:

```
id         count

2            22
5             7
```

I need a SELECT statement that gives me

```
id         count

1             2
2            22
3             4
5             7
```

Comment: "It needs to be done using a join only" why

Comment: @e4c5:updated,...........

Comment: Can you give some example ?

Comment: @UnknownUser: PLease check the update

Comment: @gags Final select have only `table B`?

Comment: @UnknownUser: No, check the new update please

Comment: You can use `union` - `SELECT id, count from A union select id, count from B;` But `union` is not a good idea on big tables.

Comment: how would union remove the duplicated and update records in old table with records in new table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join to select the data, you can use to as insert statement into a new table, but you cannot use a join to execute both insert and update statements.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Can I have a result set with select statement instead that gives me the same results instead of having to update any of the tables

Comment: Just realized that's what you said. So, I need to know a select query for that. Select query that gives me all the data from new table and old table without the rows in old table that are in new table but the updated ones instead

Answer (score 0):

Join is for doing query, not for doing insert or update.
In MySql the simplest way to do your job is:

```
REPLACE INTO old_data SELECT * FROM new_data;
```